# Is it possible to browse groups by category in the new Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

In the old interface version of Google Groups there seems to be no way to browse groups by category. It is only possible to browse all groups at once. And they call that browsing... I call it showing all groups at once, nothing else. So you have to either "browse" all groups, or you don't browse at all.

[image: new google groups interface]

While viewing the [Home](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!overview) page, if I click on the [Browse all](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forumsearch/) link it brings me to the "group search results for all groups" page and it lists the first 15 or 16 groups and as I scroll down it loads more and more groups to the list. It simply lists all groups there are.

[image: group search results for all groups]

The second option you have if you want to find a group is to use the search field and type in its' name. But these are two different concepts. If I knew the name of the group, I wouldn't be browsing for it, would I? So I mean browsing groups by category is a way to discover new groups, groups whose names you don't know yet.

1. Is this possible to do in the new Google Groups interface?
2. If not, is there a known workaround for this?

**Update:** From here, I tried switching back to the old version of the interface and [this is](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/?hl=en) where it brought me. This is supposed to be the old classic Google Groups home page with group categories. But instead it only shows the "Browse all groups" link and a search field for typing in the name of the group.

[image: the old google groups interface home]

What happened to all the categories?

If I click the "browse all groups" [link](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/groups/dir?hl=en) it brings up the list of all groups, just as I would use the new interface. So right now the old version of the interface is kind of behaving the same way as the new one. So now I can't even use the old one.

[image: all groups listing]

What is this?...

This is what it is supposed to look like:

[image: http://blogs.chatham.edu/technology/files/2012/02/Google-Groups-Start.png]

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the URLs...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. Google Groups have change again, Google no longer use Google Groups as the platform for the Product communities.